# How to activate a layer in QGIS layers legend

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, editing

How can I activate a layer in qgis map legend automatically using python code .
I am using

```
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(self.theLayerToEdit)
```

but the layer is still not checked in the maplegend.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, that is the correct code for setting the active layer in the legend. You have not provided a version for QGIS that you are using, but looking at some of your other questions, I'm going to assume 1.8 (I recommend upgrading to 2.0).

There have been numerous user-interaction GUI updates for the layer legend between 1.8->2.0. Namely, the active layer is now underlined. This is to help distinguish it from the items in the legend that are selected, or inside a multi-selection. This means setting the active layer does not necessarily also select it (and in the case of 1.8, may show no other clues it is the active layer). The opposite is also true; it is possible to programmatically have no active layer, but still have selected items.

To test that your code is working, open a project with multiple different layers, select the first one, then try the following in PyQGIS console:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
lyr.name()  # name of currently selected layer

# now manually select a different layer, making it the active layer
iface.activeLayer().name()  # prints name of new active layer

# now reset the active layer via code
iface.setActiveLayer(lyr)
iface.activeLayer().name()  # prints name of first active layer
```

If the above code works for you, but your code does not, then you may not be passing a valid [QgsMapLayer](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html) subclass to `setActiveLayer(QgsMapLayer)`. Or, there are other issues with your code/script/plugin.

If you are looking to set the layer checked (i.e. set it's visibility), then use [QgsLegendInterface](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsLegendInterface.html):

```
iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(lyr, False)
```